# In Windows 2012 Task Manager CPU Performance chart, what do the 2 data series represent?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, task-manager

I've searched everywhere for this. What do the 2 different traces on this picture mean? Is one the kernel CPU cycles?

One series is in light blue and the other in dark blue

This is an Azure Virtual Machine seen in Task Manager performance tab as an AMD Opteron Processor 4171 HE

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the Dark one is Kernel Time. If you right-click on the graph, you can disable the display of kernel-time

Comment: The thing that confused me is when I first start Task Manager, the 2 data series are visible. When I right click the chart, show kernel is NOT ticked. If I tick it, the display does not change. If I un-tick it, only one data series is shown. If I then re-tick it, the 2 series show up. And on the final right click, show kernel is ticked!

Comment: Sounds funny... maybe something special with azure. does not happen here

Comment: Same issue as Brian reported. With a 'fresh' instance of Windows Server 2012 R2 if you've never ticked 'Show kernel times' you see it but option is not checked.